# Vite is not working after i installed console ninja

Tags: javascript, vite, vscode-extensions

I recently installed console ninja and now there is an error when using vite build and vite dev it says

```
/pathToDir/node_modules/.bin/vite: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/pathToDir/node_modules/.bin/vite: line 2: `/* build-hook-start *//*00001*/try { require('/home/user/.vscode/extensions/wallabyjs.console-ninja-1.0.271/out/buildHook/index.js').default({tool: 'vite'}); } catch(cjsError) { try { import('file:///home/user/.vscode/extensions/wallabyjs.console-ninja-1.0.271/out/buildHook/index.js').then(m => m.default.default({tool: 'vite'})).catch(esmError => {}) } catch(esmError) {}}/* build-hook-end */'
```

This is what i found in /pathToDir/node_modules/.bin/vite

```
/* build-hook-start *//*00001*/try { require('/pathToDir/.vscode/extensions/wallabyjs.console-ninja-1.0.271/out/buildHook/index.js').default({tool: 'vite'}); } catch(cjsError) { try { import('file:///pathToDir/.vscode/extensions/wallabyjs.console-ninja-1.0.271/out/buildHook/index.js').then(m => m.default.default({tool: 'vite'})).catch(esmError => {}) } catch(esmError) {}}/* build-hook-end */
```

I tried removing the extensions, Reinstalling the node_modules but it still dosent work,tried creating new projects too and they all have some error.

Comment: Have you looked at console ninja's GH issues page to see if it's already been reported/solved?

Comment: The problem was the bun cache i cleared the cache from the bun folder and it worked ty for your time